# Path to gettext locales directory

Tags: python, gtk, localization, gettext

I want add locales support to my python app, but I have problem with path to directory with translates. Defualt is /usr/share/locale, but what is recommended method to define it?

1. Writing path in source code
2. Using special function to discover it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define the directory, Python's [gettext](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html) module can find it by itself on at least Linux. Just follow the [instructions in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html#internationalizing-your-programs-and-modules) and it should work.